# Do all browsers on iOS use WKWebview or UIWebVIew?

Tags: ios, google-chrome, uiwebview, wkwebview, chrome-ios

I am curious about third part browser on iOS（Chrome or FireFox）

Does all of them use the `WkWebview` or `UIWebVIew` to show then web page, but do many extra work like cache etc?

So, if I want to write a browser on iOS, I must use `WkWebview` to show the web page and wrapping it to do more stuff？

Comment: You must use the web engine (WebKit) from Apple. Thus you may use `UIWebView`, `WKWebView` or `SFSafariViewController`.

Comment: I see, unlike in Android, may be I can wrapping a 'WebView' by compile one web engine myself, in iOS, i can only use those three API offer by Apple?

Comment: @clemens, that should be an answer, not comments.

Comment: @BorysVerebskyi: I've added this as an answer.

Answer (score 24):

Yes, Apple forbids other web engines explicitly (or only allows the WebKit respectively) in [§ 2.5.6 of App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/):

> **2.5.6** Apps that browse the web must use the appropriate WebKit framework and WebKit Javascript.